# How to embed html images in xaringan self-contained slides

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

The following slide can be previewed after knit but after moving the slide to elsewhere, the images can no longer be displayed.

```
---
title: "Journal club"
author: "Timing Liu"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: 
      - default
      - default-fonts
    self_contained: true
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

<img src = 2021-01-19-23-07-58.png />
```

The documentation of `?moon_reader` shows the following:

```
should not contain the string "/>" when it is written with the syntax  <img src="PATH" />
```

I believe my path should already fit meet the criteria and therefore I am not sure why html images are not rendered. The images loaded with markdown syntax like `![](2021-01-19-23-07-58.png)` can be loaded elsewhere in the self-contained slides.

Tried with Firefox and Chrome on Windows with latest Xaringan.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider using ```knitr::include_graphics```?

Comment: I find html more flexible in terms of positioning and formatting. But you are right I should give it a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't have access to your image, here is a working example:

```
---
title: "Journal club"
author: "Timing Liu"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: 
      - default
      - default-fonts
    self_contained: true
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

<img src = "https://blog.hostonnet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/galaxy.jpg" />
```

Output (page 2/2):[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The paths were two images that I used. One require html adjustment but the other works with just markdown syntax. Adding/removing the quotes did not seem to have an impact?

Comment: I see. Could you please try ```<img src = "./2021-01-19-23-07-58.png" />```?

Comment: Thanks! I do not think that will work because it did not work when 2021-01-19-23-07-58.png was under asset/

did it work for you?

The `knitr` solution might be the way out but I am wondering if there is any way for html since it is included in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, it worked fine for me. I am going to edit my answer with a working example.

Comment: I now think the answer is multifactorial - Firefox sometimes has an issue with local images and Chrome can display it properly, but your answer on knitr has helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will also display some local pictures that are missing in Firefox.